# why am I getting segmentation fault instead of a garbage value output?

Tags: c++, memory-management, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

The following piece of code always gives garbage value as output. I am aware of the reasoning behind it as a dangling pointer is created which still points to the memory location which is freed and reoccupied by a garbage value hence dereferencing it should also give the same garbage value.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *p = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = 10;
    free(p);
    cout<<*p;
}
```

but applying the same analogy to the following code should also give a garbage value but instead it is always giving segfault. Is there anyway to tell when we will get a segfault and when we will get a garbage value?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int*myv()
{
    int a = 90;
    return &a;
}

int main()
{
    int*p = myv();
    cout<<*p;            
}
```

Also, it will be a great help if somebody could concisely explain segmentation fault and the mechanism involving allocation-deallocation of memory in simpler language.

Comment: Both of these have _undefined behavior_. That means you have _no guarantee whatsoever_ on what the programs will do.

Comment: So, you want someone to dig into the details of how stack and heap allocations work on your system to explain the (undefined) behavior you're seeing?  I think you'd need to tell us what operating system and compiler you are using.

Comment: Related: [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: *"the following code should also give a garbage value"* - says *who* ? Not the language standard. You imply some semblance of defined behavior, of which you have none in this case.